# Django Admin Page - Export fields + callable fields

Tags: django, django-1.11, django-import-export

Django Version: 1.11
Python: 2.7
Package: `django-import-export`

I am attempting to export the "callable" fields for a Django Admin page. (Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

In their example, they have a "callable" for their PersonAdmin `list_display`.

```
def upper_case_name(obj):
    return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'

class PersonAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = (upper_case_name,)
```

For the Resource, I thought I would also be able export the callable field.

```
class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ( "first_name",
               "last_name",
               "upper_case_name", )
```

However, I will get Person has no field named `upper_case_name`.
Is there a way to export callable fields?

From the documentation, it does look like you can export fields that do not exist.

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Their example was:

```
from import_export.fields import Field

class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    full_title = Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def dehydrate_full_title(self, book):
        return '%s by %s' % (book.name, book.author.name)
```

I replicated this and tried:

```
class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    upper_case_name = Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def dehydrate_upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
```

I attempted to do the same thing but I would get the error Person has no field named `upper_case_name`.
Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are two ways to do this:

**Method 1**

From: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_fields.html

- attribute – A string of either an instance attribute or **callable off the object.**

Add a callable function in the model.

```
    class Person(models.Model):

        def get_upper_case_name(self):
            return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
        upper_case_name = property(get_upper_case_name)
```

Now within the PersonResource file, declare the new custom field.

```
class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    upper_case_name = Field(attribute="get_upper_case_name", column_name="Upper Case Name")

    class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ( "first_name",
               "last_name",
               )
```

**Method 2**

This can all be done in the Resource:

```
class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    upper_case_name = fields.Field(column_name="Upper Case Name")

    def dehydrate_upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ( "first_name",
                   "last_name",
                   "upper_case_name"
                   )
```

Cheers!